# MYSQL/JAVA - How to order numbers like this?

Tags: java, mysql

I am having a problem. How to order numbers that are sorted like this?

```
1.06.1.06.01.01.01       
1.06.1.06.01.01.01.19     
1.06.1.06.01.01.01.21    
1.06.1.06.01.01.01.22    
1.06.1.06.01.01.02
```

[image]

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Can you include some code which would show how this data is being stored?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT thatColumn FROM thatTable ORDER BY CAST(thatColumn AS CHAR)

Answer (score 0):

If data coming from db is just made of strings preformatted, where dots are placed always in the same position, you can sort "numbers" lexicographically: just put each string in a TreeSet then pop them out with a iterator. E.g.

```
Set<String> cuteNumbers = new TreeSet<>();
cuteNumbers.add("1.06.1.01.01.01.01");
cuteNumbers.add(...); // etc etc
for (String number : cuteNumbers) {
   System.out.println(number);
}
```